# What's equal the below power nested radical?

Tags: exponentiation, nested-radicals

it is [well known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadical.html) that

$$\frac{2}{\pi}=\sqrt{\frac12}{\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{\frac12}}{\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{\frac12}}}{\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{\frac12\cdots}}}}}$$

My Idea is to know what about above product if it is a power as shown below :
$A=\sqrt{\frac12}^{\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{\frac12}}^{\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{\frac12}}}^{\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{\frac12\cdots}}}}}$ ?

Comment: Why do you expect that something pretty will come out of this? Generally, exponents tend to produce not so pretty results.

Comment: Each term lie between (0,1) may this give a pretty result

Comment: $.725something$. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u2qyo0gshs

Comment: By a derivable approximation we get $A\approx 2\frac{W\left(2^{-1.1}\ln\left(2\right)\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}\simeq 0.725581$

Comment: This infinite product often goes under the moniker: Viete's formula and has a nice several nice interpretations here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula#Derivation

Answer (score 0):

First, let us try to find out what $\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{...}}$ can evaluate to.

By a recursive trick, we can set up an equation as below

$$x = \sqrt{\frac12+\frac12x}\to x^2-\frac12x-\frac12=0$$

So, $x=-0.5,1$. Now, we note that the radical could not converge to $-0.5$ as the number of recursive units grows, so if it even converges, it would approach $1$.

That's not terribly helpful, since $x^1=x$ for all $x$. But, what could be useful is seeing how fast it converges to $1$, to see how many terms we need to carefully look at in the exponentiation.

We note that if $f(a) =\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12a}$ and $b=\sqrt{\frac12}$ (Inspired by commenter @Mason), then $$f(f(f(f(f(b)))))\sim0.9996988$$

So, 4 levels of recursion should be very close to the final limit value of this exponentiation, which gives us an approximation of $0.725657309196$. I will add more to this answer if I find a more satisfying approach.

Comment: http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc. Doesn't know much about this number.

Comment: In explicit terms, $$A = \left(\cos\tfrac{\pi}{4}\right)^{\left(\cos\tfrac{\pi}{8}\right)^{\left(\cos\tfrac{\pi}{16}\right)^{\ldots}}}$$

Comment: Mathematica is finding a different result than desmos. Weird